# TypeError: weather_at_place() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python

I imported a library called "pyown" to have localization with python, and I installed another library too, which calls requests to have meteorological data.

My script:

---

```
import pyown
import requests

res = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/')
data = res.json()
Cidade = str(data['city'])
Pais = str(data['country'])
Pais2 = Pais.lower()

observation = owm.weather_at_place(Cidade ,   ','   , Pais2)
w = observation.get_weather()
temperature = w.get_temperature('celsius')
wind = w.get_wind()
```

---

I got this error:

```
observation = owm.weather_at_place(Cidade , ' , ' , Pais2)
TypeError: weather_at_place() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: It means that you are giving to the function too much arguments.

Comment: Make sure the inputs passed to `weather_at_place()` have the same formats of the one in the declaration of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like from the documentation (https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pyowm/latest/pyowm.pdf), you want to have the city and country as a single string. Try something like:

`observation = owm.weather_at_place(Cidade + ',' + Pais2)`

or

`observation = owm.weather_at_place('{},{}'.format(Cidade, Pais2))`

Comment: Muito obrigado, o código funcionou

Comment: @Only_A_Perfil de nada

Answer (score 0):

try only giving it 2 arguments.

observation = owm.weather_at_place(Cidade,Pais2)

Comment: Isso não ajuda, pois eu recebo o erro "TypeError: weather_at_place() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" e no codigo original o país e a cidade tem que ser separados por uma vírgula na string

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `weather_at_place` method from the code:
https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/blob/master/pyowm/weatherapi25/owm25.py#L210

```
 def weather_at_place(self, name):
     """
     Queries the OWM Weather API for the currently observed weather at the
     specified toponym (eg: "London,uk")
     :param name: the location's toponym
     :type name: str or unicode
     :returns: an *Observation* instance or ``None`` if no weather data is available
     :raises: *ParseResponseException* when OWM Weather API responses' data cannot be parsed or *APICallException* when OWM Weather API can not be reached
     """
```

You can see that it only accepts the `name` as a single string.

You can also check and follow the examples from the documentation:
https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-examples-v2/weather-api-object-model.html#the-owm25-class

> CURRENT WEATHER QUERYING
>   `* find current weather at a specific location ---> eg: owm.weather_at_place('London,UK')`